# passing the selected item to jsp

Tags: java, html, database, jsp

I'm trying to get the selected item from a drop down list (in the same jsp page) and pass it to the WHERE statement in my query but i'm unable to do it successfully, how can I pass the selected item to jsp code?

```
<%
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection conn3 =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Registration", "user", "root");
    Statement statement3 =conn3.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs3 = statement3.executeQuery("select ABSTRACT from App.PAPERSUB2 where PAPERNAME= '"+ "How_TO_GET_THE_SELECTED_ITEM" + "'") ;

     if (rs3.next())
       System.out.println(rs3.getString(1));
 %>
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701031/how-do-i-pass-javascript-values-to-scriptlet-in-jsp

Comment: Can you please provide a link to guide me on doing that with jQuery?? I have no idea how jQuery works.

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I want to get the selected item from dropdownlist in html and use it in my jsp code.

Comment: it is java code enclosed between <% .... %>

Comment: Why u are writing java code in jsp.It is not correct approach

Comment: It is probably less used nowadays having Java inside `<% .. %>` in a `.jsp` file but it is not an incorrect approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined your combo box like this:

```
<select id="choose" name="choose">
  <option value="one" >One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

When the user submits the form, the browser sends the selected option value as a GET or a POST parameter (depending on the form's action method) `choose`.

In the JSP which processes the request you can use the predefined variable `request` to extract the parameter:

```
<%
String choosen = request.getParameter("choose");
if(choosen != null) {
%>
Selected value id: <%= choosen %>
<%
}
%>
```

**Warning**
Please don't use string concatenation to build your SQL. This can lead to a security hole. See [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use a [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead to escape the user input.