# How can i get value of Javascript function, inside jsp?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

This is my demo.jsp page

```
<head>
    <script>           
        function source(key){
            var k=document.getElementById(key);
            var UserSelectedOption = k.options[k.selectedIndex].text;
            alert(UserSelectedOption);               
        }           
    </script>
```

```
<body>
    <%
       //How can i get UserSelectedOption value here;
    %>
</body>
```

Here i'm getting UserSelectedOption is "hello",how can i use it inside jsp body page.thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass JavaScript values to Scriptlet in JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701031/how-do-i-pass-javascript-values-to-scriptlet-in-jsp)

Comment: is there any other way to do this?you suggested link is not working properly

Comment: it is still not clear what you want to achieve. Please be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to only show the content, you can show in a div

```
<body>
   <div id="divId"></div>  
</body>
```

//-------//

```
function source(key){
            var k=document.getElementById(key);
            var UserSelectedOption = k.options[k.selectedIndex].text;
            alert(UserSelectedOption);               
            document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML=UserSelectedOption;
        }
```