# Need to refer to Java global variable from js file

Tags: javascript, java

I simply need to refer to a variable from a Java class in my js file, but I am not able to do it.
Here is what I have:

```js
public class MyClass.java{
    public final static String JAVA_VARIABLE = "abc";
}
```

`testJsp` has `script.js` included

**I need to declare the variable x, from the java file, something like below:**

`script.js`:

```js
function this_is_called(){
    //The below is not working
    var x = '<%=MyClass.JAVA_VARIABLE %>'; 
}
```

Is there some way in which I can refer to the variable declared in `MyClass.java` from `script.js`?

Comment: have you imported tag library

Comment: one further alternative would be to create a REST service which allows reading that value. Depending on how your complete program looks this is also viable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test.jsp file you can assign your Java variable to a global JavaScript variable.

```
<script>var JAVA_VARIABLE = '<%=MyClass.JAVA_VARIABLE %>';</script>
```

Then access it in your script.js file

```
function this_is_called(){
    //The below is not working
    var x = JAVA_VARIABLE;
}
```

You just need to ensure the first step is before the script.js file is loaded.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Dalton,
this works perfect. 
Actually, what I needed was to declare the class fie, something like this:
var VARIABLE_CLASS ='<%=MyClass%>'
And then use its global variables like this:
 var x =' <%=MyClass.var1%>'
var y = ' <%=MyClass.var2%>'
var z = ' <%=MyClass.var3%>'

is this possible?

Comment: @SaurabhJ No problem. If this solved your issue, feel free to click the tick next to answer to flag it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link where you can find answer to this question.

[Passing java value to javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701031/how-do-i-pass-javascript-values-to-scriptlet-in-jsp)

Hope this must be Helpful!

Comment: Thanks srikanth,
but the problem is, I need to refer to the java variable inside the .js file, whereas the above is being done in the jsp script

Comment: ok than i think the solution provided by Richard Dalton is workable