# passing variable from java script to jsp script let

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to pass a java script  var to script let in jsp.
i tried many things but not working anything.can anyone tell me a working solution.

i have tried [How do I pass JavaScript values to Scriptlet in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701031/how-do-i-pass-javascript-values-to-scriptlet-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

the way this other post stays, is the correct one.

**1-** create an ajax call (in Javascript) in your webpage to send your desired params to another page.

**2-** create a page (in jsp) where you request the data sent by the #1.

That's the correct way to go.

**#1** Here's an example on how to make an ajax call, you need this on step #1, if your using jquery is simple as:

```js
String data1 = "myData1";
String data2 = "myData2";
String your_jsp_page_to_request = "myJspPage.jsp";

$.post(your_jsp_page_to_request,
    { param1: data1, param2: data2 },
    function(data){
       alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**#2** Then in your jsp you need to request the data sent, just using:

```
String data1 = request.getParameter("param1");
String data2 = request.getParameter("param2");
```